# Rich response on Dialogflow integrated with android sdk

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

Is there a way to use rich responses like suggestion chips etc. on a chatbot which is integrated with android sdk? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rich responses are not supported in Dialogflow Android client library till now. You need to write your custom code to render the UI to cards and suggestion chips. For more reading refer [here](https://miningbusinessdata.com/reader-question-rich-controls-in-dialogflow-android-integration/).

**How to render rich controls in your Android app**

- look into the client library code and see how it parses the JSON coming back from the REST API call
- add your own code to extract information about the suggestion chip controls
- write code to render these suggestion chips based on what comes back in the JSON

NOTE:
Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095058/6630837) to know more about integrating dialogflow with android

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can refer the answer I have given in the notes to get an idea, also there is a sample app available here https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/DialogflowChat please check it.